# jQuery each line in textarea

Tags: jquery

**html**

```
<textarea id="gps" name="gps"></textarea>
<button>Click</button>
```

**jquery**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var arrayOfLines = $('#gps').val().split('\n');
    $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
        $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);         
    });
});
```

I am trying to output each line individually so that I can use them later on but at the moment the above seems to split each line and then place each letter as an object

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eXeyuQa/1)

Comment: Well. That's what you're doing with `$(this)`, don't you ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are placing a string into a jQuery object. Just use the `item` instead:

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  var arrayOfLines = $('#gps').val().split('\n');
  arrayOfLines.forEach(item => console.log(item));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="gps" name="gps">28.73514, -147.42323
4.09974, 66.93197
49.11390, 48.85446</textarea>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: More precisely, OP's constructing the jQuery object not with a string but with an instance of String. Doesn't matter but that's an interesting fact about $.each.

Answer (score 1):

Inside .each loop line id 'item' object, not 'this'.

```
<textarea id="gps" name="gps"></textarea>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  $('#btn').click(function(){
      var arrayOfLines = $('#gps').val().split('\n');
      $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
          console.log('here is line:', item);         
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not dealing with "this" properly.  Try the following:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var arrayOfLines = $('#gps').val().split('\n');
  $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

Note that the "this" variable in the inner function starts with the newline, I believe.  But this should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use the html tags in this manner for this you have to specify and ID for each tag and then access in the jQuery function.

```
 <textarea id="gps" name="gps"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var arrayOfLines = $('#gps').val().split('\n');
    $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
        $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);         
    });
});
```