# How to detect if previous line in a textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to detect the structure of a single line in a textarea. For example this is my textarea and it's contents

```
this is the first line in textarea
1234 this is the second line starting with 1234

this is the fourth line and the third line is empty
```

So I want to detect empty lines like `line 3` and also detect the first 4 characters of a line like `line 2`. Is this possible with jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery each line in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858412/jquery-each-line-in-textarea)

Comment: You want to detect empty lines and do *what* with them? To answer your questions: yes it's possible to detect empty lines, and yes it is possible to detect the first 4 characters in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in textarea is simply a string, which you can split at newlines to get each line.

```
var arrayOfLines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
var finalString = "";
var prevBoolean = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
    var line = arrayOfLines[i];

    if (line.length === 0) {
       console.log("empty line");
    } else {
        // if the first 4 characters of the line are "1234" set prevBoolean to true
        if (line.substring(0, 4) == "1234"){
            finalString += line + "\n";
            prevBoolean = true;
        } else {
            // add custom line, if the previous non-empty line started with "1234" and set prevBoolean back to false
            if (prevBoolean == true) {
                 prevBoolean = false;
                 finalString += "custom line" + "\n";
             } else {
                 finalString += line + "\n";
             }

        }
    }
}

// set the value of the textarea to the finalString
$('textarea').val(finalString);
```

Comment: To add some explanation here, you can capture the value of the textarea and split it up by line breaks.  These are where the user hits enter, not where text wraps.  You are then able to iterate over the lines of text and test them however you like.  In your case, you want to look for empty lines or examine the contents of non-blank lines.

Comment: Thanks, but please for example, I want to change the value of `line 4` if the previous line starts with `1234` please how do I do that?

Comment: @TheKingis check the edit in my post. It should do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler, more concise solution using `$.each()` as we can iterate through the object, and check for *empty* lines and/or lines that begin with `1234`:

```
const arr = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
$.each(arr, (k, v) => {
    if (v.length === 0) console.log(k + ' is empty');
    if (v.substring(0, 4) == 1234) console.log('1234 found in key: ' + k);
});
```